# SpinLock read_lock_irqsave flags attribute

Tags: synchronization, linux-kernel, device-driver

This is regarding the `void spin_lock_irqsave(spinlock_t *lock, unsigned long flags);` function call. It is mentioned that previous interrupt state is stored in flags and we can restore them by passing this to `spin_unlock_irqrestore` function.

But I did not get how flags which is passed by values captures the previous interrupt state when `spin_lock_irqsave` is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`spin_lock_irqsave` is a macro, not a function.  So it can assign to `flags` even though it's apparently passed by value.

See:

http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.35.4/include/linux/spinlock.h#L312
http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.35.4/include/linux/spinlock.h#L187